# How to share images in Zoom meetings showing only the image?

Tags: windows, images, screen-sharing, zoom-meeting

Is there a way to share an image so that other users only see the image? I mean, yes I know you can open this image with the "Windows Photos" app and share this window. But this is not very professional because people would see many buttons and other things that you don't want to show like the title bar, edit button, arrows, etc ...

Is it possible to share an image in the same way that Zoom allows you to share videos? Natively or with third-party software.

Maybe with an app that would let you open a picture in an independent simple window, without borders, bars, menus, or buttons. Just with the image and another window to control it.

Comment: Software recommendation requests are not entertained here. Also, the definition of "professional" in this context is open to interpretation and will elicit opinion rather than fact.

Comment: @music2myear Edited

Comment: You can use https://recorder.easeus.com/screenshot.html to take screenshot and easily share on zoom with good quality images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1)** A **professional** solution is to insert your images in a powerpoint or similar presentation software. First start the presentation, then share the presentation in Zoom.

**Solution 2)** **Only using Zoom** and any photo software, you can go on "share screen -> advanced -> portion of screen", so you can select exactly what you want to share. Be careful as this will capture independently of the application any window(s) which is in the foreground. Zoom will remember the position of the shared portion between subsequent shares, even in different meetings, so you can start an empty meeting and set up your screen, close that meeting and only then enter the meeting in which you want to share your images.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using your own screen for anything else, you could find an image display program with a "full screen" option and share the full screen.

Alternatively, on some platforms, Zoom has a "Share Screen / Advanced" option to share a video without window borders.  If you can turn the image into a silent video lasting longer than your talk, you can then play that video to Zoom, and interrupt it when you want the image removed.

To turn an image into a video, I used Unix command-line tools.  (There are probably other ways for those who don't like the command line.)

First, I make a 30-minute silent WAV file for the audio track:

```
sox -n -r 44100 silence.wav trim 0 1800
```

Then I get `ffmpeg` to combine the picture with the silent audio:

```
ffmpeg -i silence.wav -loop 1 -i picture.jpg -shortest -vcodec mpeg4 -b:v 800k picture.mp4
```

and then I tell Zoom to share picture.mp4 to the meeting.

Edit: this does not work with all Zoom versions: some of them fail to play the resulting video, either giving a format error or hanging on "started screen sharing" (even if the OS's default player does play the video successfully), so test first.